# Is it possible to find $\tan\theta$ by squaring both sides of $\sec\theta+\tan\theta=5$ right away?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

From $\sec\theta+\tan\theta=5$, in order to find $\tan\theta $ we can rewrite it as $\sec\theta=5-\tan\theta$ then square,

$$1+\tan^2\theta=\tan^2\theta-10\tan\theta+25\quad\Rightarrow\quad \tan\theta=\frac{24}{10}$$

But When I square the both sides of $\sec\theta+\tan\theta=5$ right away I get,

$$(1+\tan^2\theta)+\tan^2\theta+2\tan\theta\sec\theta=25$$
$$\tan^2\theta+\tan\theta\sec\theta=12$$
I'm wondering is it possible to find $\tan\theta$ from above equation?

Comment: Hint :-         $\sec^{2}(x)-\tan^{2}(x)=1$

Answer (score 4):

Expanding my comment,
$$\sec(x)+\tan(x)=5 \tag 1 $$
Multiply by $\sec(x)-\tan(x)$ on both sides,
$$1=5(\sec(x)-\tan(x))$$
$$\sec(x)-\tan(x)=\frac{1}{5}\tag 2 $$
Subtracting $(1),(2)$ we have that,
$$ 2\tan(x)=5-\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\tan(x)=\frac{12}{5}$$

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, not really.

In effect if $z=\tan \theta$ and $-\frac \pi 2 \lt \theta \lt \frac \pi 2$ then $\sec\theta+\tan\theta=5$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{1+z^2} +z=5$

If you just square both sides you then get $z^2 +z\sqrt{1+z^2}=12$ which does not take you forward; you still have the radical

while if you square both sides of $\sqrt{1+z^2} =5-z$ you get $1+z^2=z^2-10z +25$ and the solution $z=\frac{24}{10}$ as you found

Comment: RAHUL's method is to multiply both sides of $\sqrt{1+z^2} +z=5$ by $\sqrt{1+z^2} -z$ to get $1=5(\sqrt{1+z^2} -z)$ and $\sqrt{1+z^2} -z=\frac15$ so by subtraction  $2z=5-\frac15$

Answer (score 2):

By @RAHUL's hint I found this continuation:

I use the abbreviations $s$ and $t$ respectively for $\sec\theta$ and $\tan \theta$.

$$t^2+st=12(s^2-t^2)$$
$$t(s+t)=12(s-t)(s+t)$$

Since $s+t=5\neq0$ we can cancel it to get $\;12(s-t)=t$ Hence $s=\frac{13}{12}t$. Substituting it in $s+t=5$ gives $t=\frac{12}5.$